# How to install kendo grid using the command line

Tags: node.js, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

http 304 https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-intl

I am trying to install kendo grid using the command : 
npm install -S @progress/kendo-angular-grid
and I am following the tutorial:
[kendoAngularLink](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/)

I am using:
Visual Studio 2015 Pro 
npm is 3.10.3
node is 6.6.0
http://registry.npmjs.org
Windows 7 SP1

Command Line Error:

```
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
npm ERR! <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
npm ERR! <style type="text/css">
npm ERR! <!--
npm ERR! body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
npm ERR! fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
npm ERR! h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
npm ERR! h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
npm ERR! h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
npm ERR! #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
npm ERR! background-color:#555555;}
npm ERR! #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
npm ERR! .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
npm ERR! -->
npm ERR! </style>
npm ERR! </head>
npm ERR! <body>
npm ERR! <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
npm ERR! <div id="content">
npm ERR!  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
npm ERR!   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
npm ERR!   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
npm ERR!  </fieldset></div>
npm ERR! </div>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sajaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularRouteTest\AngularRouteTest\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
npm ERR! <head>
npm ERR! <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
npm ERR! <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
npm ERR! <style type="text/css">
npm ERR! <!--
npm ERR! body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
npm ERR! fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
npm ERR! h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
npm ERR! h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
npm ERR! h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
npm ERR! #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
npm ERR! background-color:#555555;}
npm ERR! #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
npm ERR! .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
npm ERR! -->
npm ERR! </style>
npm ERR! </head>
npm ERR! <body>
npm ERR! <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
npm ERR! <div id="content">
npm ERR!  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
npm ERR!   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
npm ERR!   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
npm ERR!  </fieldset></div>
npm ERR! </div>
npm ERR! </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sajaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularRouteTest\AngularRouteTest\npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log:

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'install',
    1 verbose cli   '-S',
    1 verbose cli   '@progress/kendo-angular-grid' ]
    2 info using npm@3.10.3
    3 info using node@v6.6.0
    4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
    5 silly install loadCurrentTree
    6 silly install readLocalPackageData
    7 silly fetchPackageMetaData @progress/kendo-angular-grid@^0.3.3
    8 silly fetchNamedPackageData @progress/kendo-angular-grid
    9 silly mapToRegistry name @progress/kendo-angular-grid
    10 silly mapToRegistry scope (from package name) @progress
    11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
    12 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
    12 silly mapToRegistry   raw: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   scope: '@progress',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: '@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   name: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
    12 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
    13 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid
    14 verbose request uri https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid
    15 verbose request no auth needed
    16 info attempt registry request try #1 at 4:31:04 PM
    17 verbose request using bearer token for auth
    18 verbose request id b9035cea9469727e
    19 verbose etag "a81a7e8b4d7e13062eadd0015384322e"
    20 http request GET https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid
    21 http 304 https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid
    22 verbose headers { etag: '"a81a7e8b4d7e13062eadd0015384322e"',
    22 verbose headers   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
    22 verbose headers   'x-powered-by': 'TelerikNPM/1.4.3, ASP.NET',
    22 verbose headers   date: 'Thu, 06 Oct 2016 11:29:20 GMT' }
    23 silly get cb [ 304,
    23 silly get   { etag: '"a81a7e8b4d7e13062eadd0015384322e"',
    23 silly get     server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
    23 silly get     'x-powered-by': 'TelerikNPM/1.4.3, ASP.NET',
    23 silly get     date: 'Thu, 06 Oct 2016 11:29:20 GMT' } ]
    24 verbose etag https://registry.npm.telerik.com/@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid from cache
    25 verbose get saving @progress/kendo-angular-grid to C:\Users\sajaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npm.telerik.com\_40progress_252fkendo-angular-grid\.cache.json
    26 verbose correctMkdir C:\Users\sajaz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
    27 silly install normalizeTree
    28 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
    29 silly loadIdealTree Starting
    30 silly install loadIdealTree
    31 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
    32 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
    33 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
    34 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
    35 silly install loadShrinkwrap
    36 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
    37 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
    38 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
    39 silly resolveWithNewModule @progress/kendo-angular-grid@0.3.3 checking installable status
    40 silly cache add args [ '@progress/kendo-angular-grid@^0.3.3', null ]
    41 verbose cache add spec @progress/kendo-angular-grid@^0.3.3
    42 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
    42 silly cache add   raw: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid@^0.3.3',
    42 silly cache add   scope: '@progress',
    42 silly cache add   escapedName: '@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid',
    42 silly cache add   name: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    42 silly cache add   rawSpec: '^0.3.3',
    42 silly cache add   spec: '>=0.3.3 <0.4.0',
    42 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
    43 silly addNamed @progress/kendo-angular-grid@>=0.3.3 <0.4.0
    44 verbose addNamed ">=0.3.3 <0.4.0" is a valid semver range for @progress/kendo-angular-grid
    45 silly addNameRange { name: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    45 silly addNameRange   range: '>=0.3.3 <0.4.0',
    45 silly addNameRange   hasData: false }
    46 silly mapToRegistry name @progress/kendo-angular-grid
    47 silly mapToRegistry scope (from package name) @progress
    48 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npm.telerik.com/
    49 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
    49 silly mapToRegistry   raw: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   scope: '@progress',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   escapedName: '@progress%2fkendo-angular-grid',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   name: '@progress/kendo-angular-grid',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
    49 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
    50 silly mapToRegistry uri 
..............................................................................
    113 verbose bad json <!--
    113 verbose bad json body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    113 verbose bad json fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
    113 verbose bad json h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    113 verbose bad json h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
    113 verbose bad json h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
    113 verbose bad json #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    113 verbose bad json background-color:#555555;}
    113 verbose bad json #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    113 verbose bad json .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    113 verbose bad json -->
    113 verbose bad json </style>
    113 verbose bad json </head>
    113 verbose bad json <body>
    113 verbose bad json <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    113 verbose bad json <div id="content">
    113 verbose bad json  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
    113 verbose bad json   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    113 verbose bad json   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    113 verbose bad json  </fieldset></div>
    113 verbose bad json </div>
    113 verbose bad json </body>
    113 verbose bad json </html>
    114 error registry error parsing json
    115 verbose headers { 'content-type': 'text/html',
    115 verbose headers   etag: 'W/"6d-Fu7Ixs3fv/SPMAEYNY9Snw"',
    115 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    115 verbose headers   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
    115 verbose headers   'x-powered-by': 'TelerikNPM/1.4.3, ASP.NET',
    115 verbose headers   date: 'Thu, 06 Oct 2016 11:29:21 GMT',
    115 verbose headers   'content-length': '1233' }
    116 silly get cb [ 403,
    116 silly get   { 'content-type': 'text/html',
    116 silly get     etag: 'W/"6d-Fu7Ixs3fv/SPMAEYNY9Snw"',
    116 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    116 silly get     server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
    116 silly get     'x-powered-by': 'TelerikNPM/1.4.3, ASP.NET',
    116 silly get     date: 'Thu, 06 Oct 2016 11:29:21 GMT',
    116 silly get     'content-length': '1233' } ]
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <head>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <style type="text/css">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <!--
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData background-color:#555555;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData -->
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </style>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </head>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <body>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <div id="content">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData  </fieldset></div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </body>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </html>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.parse (native)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:199:23)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:172:14)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for @telerik/kendo-intl@^0.10.0 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <head>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <style type="text/css">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <!--
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData background-color:#555555;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData -->
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </style>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </head>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <body>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData <div id="content">
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData  </fieldset></div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </div>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </body>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData </html>
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.parse (native)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:199:23)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:172:14)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    117 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
    118 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
    119 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
    120 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
    121 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
    122 silly install printInstalled
    123 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    123 verbose stack <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    123 verbose stack <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    123 verbose stack <head>
    123 verbose stack <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    123 verbose stack <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
    123 verbose stack <style type="text/css">
    123 verbose stack <!--
    123 verbose stack body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    123 verbose stack fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
    123 verbose stack h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    123 verbose stack h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
    123 verbose stack h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
    123 verbose stack #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    123 verbose stack background-color:#555555;}
    123 verbose stack #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    123 verbose stack .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    123 verbose stack -->
    123 verbose stack </style>
    123 verbose stack </head>
    123 verbose stack <body>
    123 verbose stack <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    123 verbose stack <div id="content">
    123 verbose stack  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
    123 verbose stack   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    123 verbose stack   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    123 verbose stack  </fieldset></div>
    123 verbose stack </div>
    123 verbose stack </body>
    123 verbose stack </html>
    123 verbose stack
    123 verbose stack     at Object.parse (native)
    123 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:199:23)
    123 verbose stack     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:172:14)
    123 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:200:22)
    123 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    123 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    123 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1067:10)
    123 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    123 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    123 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
    124 verbose cwd C:\Users\sajaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AngularRouteTest\AngularRouteTest
    125 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    126 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-S" "@progress/kendo-angular-grid"
    127 error node v6.6.0
    128 error npm  v3.10.3
    129 error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    129 error <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    129 error <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    129 error <head>
    129 error <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    129 error <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
    129 error <style type="text/css">
    129 error <!--
    129 error body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    129 error fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
    129 error h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    129 error h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
    129 error h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
    129 error #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    129 error background-color:#555555;}
    129 error #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    129 error .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    129 error -->
    129 error </style>
    129 error </head>
    129 error <body>
    129 error <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    129 error <div id="content">
    129 error  <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
    129 error   <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    129 error   <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
    129 error  </fieldset></div>
    129 error </div>
    129 error </body>
    129 error </html>
    130 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
    130 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
    131 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have submitted the issue: [#14197](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14197)

Answer (score 2):

Kendo UI for Angular 2 is packaged and distributed as a set of discrete, scoped NPM packages, which are available at the Progress NPM registry (https://registry.npm.telerik.com/)

First run this command-

```
npm login --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress
```

Then enter user id, password and email which you have registered on Telerik site. (If you do not have Telerik account, then create one.)

After successful login using above command, you can run

```
npm install -S @progress/kendo-angular-grid
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't have a specific username but only an email to login, use the first part (before the @) of your email as username to login.

Comment: You can also login to kenod website and check your profile, you should see your username there.

Answer (score 0):

For installation:

1. Create an account with Kendo UI , Its free. :D
2. Then go to your app folder and run “`npm login
   --registry=https://registry.npm.telerik.com/ --scope=@progress`” It’ll ask you for Username and password, definitely you have to give
   one! :D
3. After that it’ll create @progress folder under node modules folder.
4. Let’s check if it’s installed or not! “`npm view
   @progress/kendo-angular-grid versions`”
5. Kendo UI is modular! So you need not to download whole package! There
   are plenty of components and can install it independently. E.g,
   Buttons : `npm install -S @progress/kendo-angular-buttons` OR `npm
   install --save @progress/kendo-angular-buttons`
6. Components : http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components
7. Go to `app.module.ts` (if you are using `Angular CLI`) and import your installed component `import {
   ButtonsModule }` from '`@progress/kendo-angular-buttons`'; Then add
   “`ButtonsModule`” under Imports property of `@NgModule` decorator.